# Как удалить строку из базы данных посредством RedBeanPHP?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Появилась необходимость удалять строку из базы данных используя фрейм RedBeanPHP. 
Надо удалить из конкретной таблицы users строку с определенным email, в документации к данному фрейму речь идет про удаление без указания таблицы...

Comment: R::exec("DELETE FROM table WHERE email = ?" , [$email]);    
Такое чем то не устраивает?

Comment: Не работает подобное выражение, кидает ошибку

Comment: а...нет...спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = 'example@email.com';
$find = R::findOne('users', 'email = ?',[$email]);
$delete = R::load('users', $find->id);
R::trash($delete);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]